# FastAPI redirect gives method not allowed error

Tags: python, http, fastapi, starlette

I have created a route for login, where I post my form data and set a cookie. After setting the cookie I redirect to "/main" where I get `{detail:"Method Not Allowed"}` as a response.

```
@app.post("/login")
async def login(request:Request):
     response = RedirectResponse(url="/main")
     response.set_cookie(key="cookie",value="key-value")
     return response

@app.get("/main")
async def root(request:Request, cookie: Optional[str] = Cookie(None)):
     if cookie:
        answer = "set to %s" % cookie
     else:
          answer = "not set"

     return {"value": answer}
```

I furthered checked the console to find that a POST request is made to "/main" during the redirect and hence causing the error. When I change it to `app.post("/main")` it works fine. How do I avoid this error? I don't want to make post request to access "/main" everytime. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that in FastAPI, starlette response by default have code 307, which preserves the method during the redirection, hence the post request. I solved this by adding `response.status_code = 302` before returning the response.

Comment: `status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER` make more sense to me. 302 status code is for not found redirection.