# fastapi (starlette) RedirectResponse redirect to post instead get method

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I have encountered strange redirect behaviour after returning a RedirectResponse object

**events.py**

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post('/create', response_model=EventBase)
async def event_create(
        request: Request,
        user_id: str = Depends(get_current_user),
        service: EventsService = Depends(),
        form: EventForm = Depends(EventForm.as_form)
):
    event = await service.post(
       ...
   )
    redirect_url = request.url_for('get_event', **{'pk': event['id']})
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url)


@router.get('/{pk}', response_model=EventSingle)
async def get_event(
        request: Request,
        pk: int,
        service: EventsService = Depends()
):
    ....some logic....
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        'event.html',
        context=
        {
            ...
        }
    )
```

**routers.py**

```
api_router = APIRouter()

...
api_router.include_router(events.router, prefix="/event")
```

this code returns the result

```
127.0.0.1:37772 - "POST /event/22 HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
```

OK, I see that for some reason a POST request is called instead of a GET request. I search for an explanation and find that the RedirectResponse object defaults to code 307 and calls POST [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66849929/fastapi-redirect-gives-method-not-allowed-error)

I follow the advice and add a status

```
redirect_url = request.url_for('get_event', **{'pk': event['id']}, status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
```

And get

```
starlette.routing.NoMatchFound
```

for the experiment, I'm changing `@router.get('/{pk}', response_model=EventSingle)` to `@router.post('/{pk}', response_model=EventSingle)`

and the redirect completes successfully, but the post request doesn't suit me here. What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

html form for running **event/create** logic

**base.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('event_create')}}" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

**base_view.py**

```
@router.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def main_page(request: Request,
                    activity_service: ActivityService = Depends()):
    activity = await activity_service.get()
    return templates.TemplateResponse('base.html', context={'request': request,
                                                            'activities': activity})
```

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804) if it helps.

Comment: with `status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER` same result `starlette.routing.NoMatchFound`

Comment: I should add that a standard html button form is used to run the code, but I don't think it matters. What other information might be useful?

Comment: I definitely don't understand from the suggested answers how I can make my code work. I'm running the logic to create an event via an html form, just like in the answers. I've added it to the question description.

Comment: Or are you telling me that the logic in my code is correct and I need to look for the problem somewhere else rather than RedirectResponse ?

Comment: @Jekson One difference from your code to my example is that you're passing the `status_code` to `url_for` instead of adding it to the `RedirectResponse`, that's probably why you're getting the `NoMatchFound`: it'strying to match a route with a parameter `status_code` and not finding it.

Comment: @EliasDorneles that's the point! I was very inattentive, incorrect syntax was the cause of the problem.

Comment: You're welcome, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you want to redirect to a GET after a POST, the best practice is [to redirect with a `303` status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303), so just update your code to:

```
    # ...
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=303)
```

As you've noticed, [redirecting with `307` keeps the HTTP method and body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307).

#### Fully working example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse


router = APIRouter()

@router.get('/form')
def form():
    return HTMLResponse("""
    <html>
    <form action="/event/create" method="POST">
    <button>Send request</button>
    </form>
    </html>
    """)

@router.post('/create')
async def event_create(
        request: Request
):
    event = {"id": 123}
    redirect_url = request.url_for('get_event', **{'pk': event['id']})
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=303)


@router.get('/{pk}')
async def get_event(
        request: Request,
        pk: int,
):
    return f'<html>oi pk={pk}</html>'

app = FastAPI(title='Test API')

app.include_router(router, prefix="/event")
```

To run, install `pip install fastapi uvicorn` and run with:

```
uvicorn --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000 example:app
```

Then, point your browser to: http://localhost:3000/event/form

Comment: with `status_code=303` same result `starlette.routing.NoMatchFound`

Comment: Well, your problem is probably elsewhere. Here is a working example: https://gist.github.com/eliasdorneles/6b2afd81cfc15ad4084d3da620bef73f (instructions how to run in the comments)

Comment: I try and got `{"detail":[{"loc":["path","pk"],"msg":"value is not a valid integer","type":"type_error.integer"}]}` . is that what you mean? But my code works if I change the get to post in the rout as I wrote above

Comment: @Jekson ah sorry, i had made a mistake in the instructions, you need to point your browser to http://localhost:3000/event/form -- and not http://localhost:3000/event/create (which will do a GET request that will fail because it will try to match against `/event/{pk}`, that's the error you saw)

Comment: @Jekson and indeed, the redirect in your code will work if you change the `GET /event/{pk}` into `POST /event/{pk}` -- but is that a good idea? IMO, it would be hurting your API design, just because of an annoyance of the framework...

Comment: This way `localhost:3000/event/form` al work correct

Answer (score 3):

The error you mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773879/fastapi-starlette-redirectresponse-redirect-to-post-istead-get-method#comment125119767_70774192) is raised because you are trying to access the `event_create` endpoint via http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/create, for instance. However, since `event_create` route handles `POST` requests, your request ends up in the `get_event` endpoint (and raises a `value is not a valid integer` error, since you are passing a string instead of integer), as **when you type a URL in the address bar of your browser, it performs a `GET` request**.

Thus, you need an [HTML `<form>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), for example, to submit a `POST` request to the `event_create` endpoint. Below is a working example, which you can use to access the HTML `<form>` at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/` (adjust the port number as desired) to send a `POST` request, which will then trigger the [`RedirectResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse).

As @tiangolo mentioned [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1498#issuecomment-647040401), when performing a `RedirectResponse` from a `POST` request route to a `GET` request route, the [**response status code has to change**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-change-status-code/) to [`303 See Other`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303). For instance:

```py
return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
```

### Working Example:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse

router = APIRouter()

# This endpoint can be accessed at http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/
@router.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def event_create_form(request: Request):
    return """
    <html>
       <body>
          <h1>Create an event</h1>
          <form method="POST" action="/event/create">
             <input type="submit" value="Create Event">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
    
@router.post('/create')
def event_create(request: Request):
    event = {"id": 1}
    redirect_url = request.url_for('get_event', **{'pk': event['id']})
    return RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)    

@router.get('/{pk}')
def get_event(request: Request, pk: int):
    return {"pk": pk}


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router, prefix="/event")
```