# FastAPI's RedirectResponse doesn't work as expected in Swagger UI

Tags: python, redirect, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui

I have a FastAPI app with a download endpoint. What this download endpoint does is to use a `BlobServiceClient` (for Azure Blob Storage) to generate a token and a Blob URL to a file specified in the request. What I want to do is to redirect the user to that URL. Here is a code snippet of the download enpoint (I commented some things out because I'm not allowed to show the code).

```py
@router.get("..path", tags=["some tags"], summary=..., responses={404: {"model": ...}, 403: {"model": ...}, 307: {"model": ...}}, response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def download_file(
        # there's a depends on an API key
        blob_path: str = Query(
            ...
        )):
credential = ClientSecretCredential(...)  //secrets
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(f"https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=credential)
user_delegation_key = blob_service_client.get_user_delegation_key(key_start_time=datetime.utcnow(),key_expiry_time=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=30))
    
token = generate_blob_sas(account_name=...,                                 
                          container_name=...,                                 
                          blob_name=blob_path,
                          user_delegation_key=user_delegation_key,
                          permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
                          expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=30))
    
blob_url = f'https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_path}?{token}' 
print(blob_url)  
response = RedirectResponse(blob_url) 
return response
```

What I expected is the query to be executed, and after the response is returned, the download to start in the background or in a separate tab. What I've got instead is a different response as you can see in the Swagger:

[image]
[image]

I also had a look in the Network tab to see what is happening with that request:

[image]
[image]

Looks like there is an `OPTIONS` request and I assume that I'm getting the response to that request. Not sure if this is how Swagger handles the request. Any idea how/why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: I understand what you are saying, the OPTIONS request returns a File response so that's why it is like that in Swagger. My question was why the OPTIONS request is done firstly (I assume because of the redirect) but why isn't that URL where I want to be redirected simply accessed (like when you click on an URL to download something and it starts downloading). Are you saying that redirect should not be followed?

Comment: What I am confused about is the functionality I'm trying to achieve which is accessing the URL and the OPTIONS request sent by Swagger to that URL

Answer (score 2):

To start with, the [HTTP OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS), in [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), is a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) that is automatically issued by the browser, before the actual request—is not the one that returns the `File` response. It requests the permitted communication options for a given server, and the server responds with an [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) header including a set of permitted methods (e.g., `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE`). The preflight response can be optionally cached for the requests created in the same URL using `Access-Control-Max-Age` header, thus allowing the server to limit the number of preflight requests. The value of this header is expressed in seconds; hence, allowing caching for 10 minutes, for example, would look as `Access-Control-Max-Age: 600`.

As for the [`RedirectResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse), [Swagger UI always follows redirect responses](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1569#issuecomment-390877095). In a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) request, for instance, the [`redirect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#syntax) parameter would be set to `follow`, indicating that the `redirect` should be followed. This means that Swagger UI follows the redirect and waits for the response to be completely received before providing you with a `Download file` link (as shown in the screenshot you provided above) that would allow you to download the file. That is also why you can't see the download starting either in the background or in a new tab. As mentioned in the linked github post above, it is not possible to change that behaviour, which could allow you to handle it differently, similar to the approach demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75188418/17865804).

Instead of using Swagger UI to test that specific endpoint, you can either test it directly through typing the URL to your API endpoint in the address bar of your browser (since it is a `GET` endpoint, you can do that, as when you type a URL in the address bar of your browser, it performs a `GET` request), or create your own custom [Template](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) (or use [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response)) and  submit an [HTML `<form>`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804).