# How to download blob(xlsx file) from azure-storage-blob using FastAPI?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, fastapi

I am trying to download the xlsx blob file from azure storage through my browser using FastAPI in the backend:

```
def download_blob(blob_service_client, filename: str, container: str):
    try:        
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container, blob=filename)
        blob_url = blob_client.url
        return FileResponse(content=blob_url, status_code=200, media_type='application/vnd.ms-excel', filename="Test.xlsx")
    except Exception as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={"message": "File is not downloaded."}, status_code=500)

# blob_url looks like this
blob_url = "https://testapp.blob.core.windows.net/test-container/test-sample.xlsx"
```

but I am getting status code 500 in response.

anybody guide me how can I download the file?

Comment: You could use [`RedirectResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse).

Comment: @Chris - I used the RedirectResponse(blob_url) and got this response:--  
`Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS
Network Failure
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

I have used:
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
origins = ["*"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)`

Comment: @Chris - Not working either

Comment: @Chris -  I am using Swagger UI. and I have mentioned the code in my question. Do let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804), in case you are using Swagger UI to test your API, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect the user to another page after login using JavaScript Fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75184430/how-to-redirect-the-user-to-another-page-after-login-using-javascript-fetch-api)