# What might be the reason my FastAPI local host does not work?

Tags: python, localhost, fastapi, dialogflow-es

We are trying to develop this chatbot with Dialogflow and fastAPI with Python to generate research papers links. The bot seems to work fine in Dialogflow but the local host with FastAPI seems to have issues. When we are trying to open localhost 8000, it says detail not found with post request. Don't really understand what's happening since we are trying to find solutions but can't. Please help.

We are trying to run local host via 8000 port as included in the code. The result should be success or something related to bot we developed. But the result is detail not found and 404 error.

@app.post("/research_papers")
async def retrieve_research_papers(request: Request):

This is the code which we included and trying to run local host using - https://127.0.0.1:8000 and also /research_papers at the end. Both doesn't seem to work. What do you believe might be the issue?

Comment: If you access `http://localhost:8000/research_papers` in your browser you're making a GET request. You've only shown code that handles a POST request (`app.post`) - you can use `app.get` if you want your controller to handle GET requests instead. Include the actual request you're making and a minimum self-contained example that shows the issue.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us how your app is, to permit us to reproduce the pb ?
Are you sure you run your app in the good directory?

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73608593/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of items come to mind with this error.

1. Inspect your endpoint paths and HTTP methods, they should be consistent between the two applications, in line with what [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) mentioned about the GET and POST.
2. Check your parameters, there might be a mismatch or missing information between the APIs hence the difficulty processing requests, these include URLs, authentication tokens, value formats, etc.

I found some articles that can be a useful reference:

- [Building a Dialogflow Chatbot with Webhook Integration for FastAPI and MongoDB](https://medium.com/@sarahanish9/building-a-dialogflow-chatbot-with-webhook-integration-for-fastapi-and-mongodb-e1fe4b1a2fb)
- [Building a Chatbot: Dialogflow, FastAPI, and GitHub in Action](https://python.plainenglish.io/building-a-chatbot-dialogflow-fastapi-and-github-in-action-33f663578f79)